# Generate all possible coverage options

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq

Suppose I have 2 lists: one containing strings, one containing integers, they differ in length. The application I am building will use these lists to generate combinations of vehicle and coverage areas. Strings represent area names and ints represent vehicle ID's.

My goal is to generate a list of all possible unique combinations used for further investigation.  One vehicle can service many areas, but one area can't be served by multiple vehicles. Every area must receive service, and every vehicle must be used.

So to conclude the constraints:

- Every area is used only once
- Every vehicle is used at least once
- No area can be left out.
- No vehicle can be left out

Here is an example:

```
public class record = {
    public string areaId string{get;set;}
    public int vehicleId int {get;set;}
}

List<string> areas = new List<string>{ "A","B","C","D"};
List<int> vehicles = new List<int>{ 1,2};

List<List<record>> uniqueCombinationLists = retrieveUniqueCombinations(areas,vehicles);
```

I just have no clue how to make the `retrieveUniqueCombinations` function. Maybe I am just looking wrong or thinking too hard. I am stuck thinking about massive loops and other brute force approaches.  An explanation of a better approach would be much appreciated.

The results should resemble something like this, I think this contains all possibilities for this example.

```
A1;B1;C1;D2
A1;B1;C2;D1
A1;B2;C1;D1
A2;B1;C1;D1
A2;B2;C2;D1
A2;B2;C1;D2
A2;B1;C2;D2
A1;B2;C2;D2
A2;B1;C1;D2
A1;B2;C2;D1
A2;B2;C1;D1
A1;B1;C2;D2
A2;B1;C2;D1
A1;B2;C1;D2
```

Comment: can you provide an example output

Comment: no, The other way around. one vehicle can service many areas, one area can't be served by multiple vehicles.

Comment: Check my edit.  I think I've better phrased your problem, but please [edit] your question if I messed up any of the details.

Comment: Your example is a bit confusing. Why is there no `A1 B1 C1 D1`?

Comment: Every vehicle should be used.

Comment: @mohammedlok I accidentally dropped that constraint.  It was part of the original problem.  I've edited the question to fix my error.

Comment: This looks a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/q/10519619/215552, except for the constraints. Really, your tile is somewhat misleading, since it's all possible unique combinations; it's most possible unique combinations...

Comment: Why do you have the return type `List<List<record>>` (missed a variable name)? How does this work? All records at index n correspond to vehicle number n or?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? A generic method to handle `n` and `m` number of areas and vehicle? Or is performance an issue? Or you have too many records and you are scared of some `OutOfMemoryException`?

Comment: If you have 150 areas and 5 vehicles, that means you are trying to arrange a minimum of 150 elements from the set on 5 elements (more combinations in your case). So how many combinations can I have? `C = 150! / {5! * (150 - 5)!}`. How can you not be afraid about memory issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So lets use some helper classes to convert numbers to `IEnumerable<int>` enumerations in different bases. It may be more efficient to use `List<>` but since we are trying to use LINQ:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> LeadingZeros(this IEnumerable<int> digits, int minLength) {
    var dc = digits.Count();
    if (dc < minLength) {
        for (int j1 = 0; j1 < minLength - dc; ++j1)
            yield return 0;
    }
    foreach (var j2 in digits)
        yield return j2;
}

public static IEnumerable<int> ToBase(this int num, int numBase) {
    IEnumerable<int> ToBaseRev(int n, int nb) {
        do {
            yield return n % nb;
            n /= nb;
        } while (n > 0);
    }

    foreach (var n in ToBaseRev(num, numBase).Reverse())
        yield return n;
}
```

Now we can create an enumeration that lists all the possible answers (and a few extras). I converted the `List`s to `Array`s for indexing efficiency.

```
var areas = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
var vehicles = new List<int> { 1, 2 };

var areasArray = areas.ToArray();
var vehiclesArray = vehicles.ToArray();
var numVehicles = vehiclesArray.Length;
var numAreas = areasArray.Length;
var NumberOfCombos = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(numVehicles, numAreas));
var ansMap = Enumerable.Range(0, NumberOfCombos).Select(n => new { n, nd = n.ToBase(numVehicles).LeadingZeros(numAreas)});
```

Given the enumeration of the possible combinations, we can convert into `areas` and `vehicles` and exclude the ones that don't use all `vehicles`.

```
var ans = ansMap.Select(nnd => nnd.nd).Select(m => m.Select((d, i) => new { a = areasArray[i], v = vehiclesArray[d] })).Where(avc => avc.Select(av => av.v).Distinct().Count() == numVehicles);
```

Comment: This is a very complete and ultrafast solution. Many thanks. I have a lot to learn and will try to disect your code.

Comment: I like this one much better than mine :).

Answer (score 3):

Here's something I threw together that may or may not work. Borrowing heavily from [dtb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76217/dtb)'s work on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10519847/215552).

Basically, I generate them all, then remove the ones that don't meet the requirements.

```
List<string> areas = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
List<int> vehicles = new List<int> { 1, 2 };

var result = retrieveUniqueCombinations(areas, vehicles);
result.ToList().ForEach((recordList) => { 
    recordList.ToList().ForEach((record) => 
        Console.Write("{0}{1};", record.areaId, record.vehicleId)); 
    Console.WriteLine(); 
});

public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<record>> retrieveUniqueCombinations(IEnumerable<string> areas, IEnumerable<int> vehicles)
{
    var items = from a in areas
                from v in vehicles
                select new record { areaId = a, vehicleId = v };
    var result = items.GroupBy(i => i.areaId).CartesianProduct().ToList();
    result.RemoveAll((records) => 
        records.All(record => 
            record.vehicleId == records.First().vehicleId));
    return result;
}

public class record
{
    public string areaId { get; set; }
    public int vehicleId { get; set; }
}


static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(
      this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
    {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
        return sequences.Aggregate(
          emptyProduct,
          (accumulator, sequence) =>
            from accseq in accumulator
            from item in sequence
            select accseq.Concat(new[] { item }));
    }
}
```

This produces the following:

```
A1;B1;C1;D2;
A1;B1;C2;D1;
A1;B1;C2;D2;
A1;B2;C1;D1;
A1;B2;C1;D2;
A1;B2;C2;D1;
A1;B2;C2;D2;
A2;B1;C1;D1;
A2;B1;C1;D2;
A2;B1;C2;D1;
A2;B1;C2;D2;
A2;B2;C1;D1;
A2;B2;C1;D2;
A2;B2;C2;D1;
```

Note that these are not in the same order as yours, but I'll leave the verification to you. Also, there's likely a better way of doing this (for instance, by putting the logic in the `RemoveAll` step in the `CartesianProduct` function), but hey, you get what you pay for ;).

Comment: Sweet! Really nice solution, but this will surely run into `OutOfMemoryException` with say 20 areas and 5 vehicles. Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: @mohammedlok Not really. This was more of a "push in the right direction" answer than a "this works for all the things!" kind of answer. I think the OP will be able to take it from here. He mentioned in comments that he'll be working out things like parallelism and memory consumption at a later time.

Comment: Nice answer. I think you could create `items` easier like so: `items = from a in areas select from v in vehicles select new { a, v }`.